# hover div to change an other div

Tags: css, html, hover

How can I prevent a child `div` `:hover` event to be overridden by its parent `:hover` event?

This is how I create the `div` element:

### HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counterd = document.createElement("div");
    counterd.id='counterdiv';
    counterd.innerHTML = "(<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ?>)";
    document.getElementById('menu-item-130').appendChild(counterd);
    document.getElementById("counterdiv").setAttribute('onclick', 'location.href = "/varukorg"');
</script>
```

The CSS to change style is:

```
#menu-item-130:hover #counterdiv, #menu-item-130.current_page_item #counterdiv {
    color: black;
}
```

I also have some CSS rules to style `#menu-item-130` on `:hover`. The problem occurs when the mouse goes over `#counterdiv`, it changes the `#counterdiv` text to black. **I don't want the `#counterdiv` element to trigger the parent's event when it is hovered.** The hover CSS for the `#menu-item` is the following:

```
#menu-item-130 a:hover, #menu-item-130.current_page_item a {
    background: url(../images/cart-59-24black.png) gray 21px 18px no-repeat!important;
}
```

and as both `div` elements have the property `position:relative;`, I have tried with `z-index` but it does not seems to work. I know that its impossible to make a parent `div` to change style when hover a child.

Edit: Hi guys i find a solution like a hardcode but its work ;) as the counter div was on top i made the #counterdiv on hover at the same size as the #menu-item-130 and puted the same backround style to it so now its work. Thanks for the help anyway..

Comment: add a fiddle please and show your html code

Comment: I think the question is good as is. There's not need for everyone to include live demos of their work, particularly for a *2 div* problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood your question, but here is an example how it could work for you:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/etadit/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The `:hover` even you already fine works fine. But there is something called **propagation**, which will make the browser detect in which parent element your cursor is, and trigger the events/pseudo-elements/pseudo-classes related to this element. In order to stop this propagation, (**in CSS**), you need to counter it with the child element's properties.

**Parent's background property:** `gray`

**Child's background property:** `transparent !important`

To understand what `!important` clearly does, I suggest you to read more about [**CSS Specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) *(MDN)*

---

### Solution

Apply a transparent background to the element itself with the `!important` notion:

### HTML

```
<div id="item-130">Item 130
    <div id="counterdiv">CounterDiv</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#item-130:hover > #counterdiv {
    background-color:gray;
}

#counterdiv:hover {
    background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kVzSA/1/)

Comment: What about using **specificity** over the use of **!important**?

Comment: I made a suggestion, I'm not his hands nor head; he does whatever he wants.

Comment: True.  

But if I'm helping someone and I knew the difference between **specificity** and how to properly use **!important** then I would show them the best/proper solution.  Not just **a** solution.  

I'm coming from the approach that `!important` should be used as an **absolute last resort**.

Comment: It's really difficult not to fall into the opinion-based answer. Sometimes it's also better to let people *find* the answer by themselves, there's always a limit to doing homework, such as no signing my name on it.